# Spring Boot OAuth2.0 Authorization Code Flow without Client Secret at Frontend

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have created an `Authorization Server` and `Resource Server` using Spring Boot OAuth2.0. I'm trying to implement `authorization code flow`. I can get the code with a GET request to

```
/oauth/token
```

endpoint. I can also get an access token if and only if I add an basic auth credentials of `client`. However, I don't want to put my `client secret` into UI. Also, I don't want to use `implicit flow` due to security concerns.

How can I get access token without exposing `client secret` into UI and using Spring Boot OAuth2.0 configuration parameters?

Comment: Is the UI also an Spring Boot App or something else?

Comment: Something else.

Comment: I'm also looking for this kind of flow. Till now I have found this https://oauth.net/2/pkce/

Comment: Have you found a resolution/answer to this?